# How to use a VB usercontrol on a C# page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

I've created a usercontrol in VB that handles paging more efficiently than the DataPager (at least for very large datasets).  I'd like to use it in a C# project, but I've been having trouble getting it to work.

I've tried simply adding PagingControl.ascx to the C# project, but when I do that the markup and VB code behind don't seem to see each other. --Is this a namespace issue?

I've tried adding the PagingControl.ascx to its own VB project, then adding that project to the C# project's solution, as well as a reference. --That almost works.  I can register the PagingControl usercontrol in the markup.  I can access the usercontrol's properties in the code behind, **but** any property that involves the UI of the usercontrol fails.

Its seems as if the usercontrol's form hasn't had a chance to load by the time the C# page's Page_Load event handler fires. --Maybe this is an "order of operations" problem?  At what point in the C# page's lifetime should a usercontrol's form be loaded?

If anyone has any ideas or insight, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but any property that involves the UI of the usercontrol fails."  What is the nature of the failure?  Are you saying it fails at design time (i.e., Intellisense is failing), or at runtime (an exception is thrown).

Comment: The error I get is: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  When debugging, if I mouse over the control names and properties, I don't get the usual popup message describing the control.  Its as if it doesn't exist (yet).  Intellisense is working when not debugging.

Comment: By "control names and properties", I mean the controls used within the usercontrol, not the usercontrol itself.

Comment: Is this a webapplication or a website project?  You can mix and match with a website project, but not with a web application project.

Comment: Its a web application project.  Maybe mix and match is out of the question within a project, but surely its possible between two projects.  Is it possible to add a C# usercontrol from one project to a C# page in another project?

Comment: You should probably look into converting the VB code to C# instead of working around it. There are automated converters on the web, such as http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have VB and C# code in one project - you have to split it and reference the VB part in the C# project. To the other question: no idea, as I don't do web dev.

Comment: So far, that seems to be the case, that VB and C# don't "play well together" when in the same project.

Comment: It is not supported in Visual Studio, yes. in #develop it actually is.

Comment: Wow.  I'll have to check that out.  I don't know if it will help with my current problem, but it does sound interesting.